# sed adding and removing and inserting characters at specific positions to every row in csv

Tags: regex, bash, csv, sed

I have the following sample data set in a csv file with approx 1M rows.

```
20090531 235850000,605.530000,606.230000,0
20090531 235922000,605.500000,606.200000,0
20090531 235930000,605.530000,606.230000,0
20090531 235939000,605.550000,606.250000,0
20090531 235945000,605.500000,606.200000,0
20090531 235946000,605.530000,606.230000,0
```

I would like to "clean" the data. as I would like it in the following format where `^` is a character to be inserted and `.` is a character to be deleted:

```
2009-05-31 23:59:46   ,605.530000,606.230000
    ^  ^     ^  ^  ...                      ..
```

I think `sed` might be the best way to go, but am not too familiar with sed and regexes, to be able to do efficiently but have come up with the following so far. I have put each regex rule on a new line to make easier to read.

```
sed '
    s/.\{4\}/&-/;
    s/.\{7\}/&-/;
    s/.\{13\}/&:/;
    s/.\{16\}/&:/' input.csv > output.csv
```

output.csv - what the above command outputs:

```
2009-05-31 23:59:06000,605.530000,606.230000,0
2009-05-31 23:59:22000,605.500000,606.200000,0
2009-05-31 23:59:30000,605.530000,606.230000,0
2009-05-31 23:59:39000,605.550000,606.250000,0
```

So all that is left to do is to remove the `000` after the seconds and remove the final `,0`

Question 1: Is there a better way than my approach to do the above operation?
Question 2: how can I remove the characters that I don't want?

Update, I have also removed the last 2 characters from each row. Now I just need to remove those 3 zeros from the time.

```
sed '
    s/.\{4\}/&-/;
    s/.\{7\}/&-/;
    s/.\{13\}/&:/;
    s/.\{16\}/&:/;
    s/.\{2\}$//' input.csv > output.csv
```

solution:

```
sed -r '
    s/^(.{4})(.{2})(.{2}) (.{2})(.{2})(.{2})000/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/;
    s/.\{2\}$//' input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the substitutions at the front in one go, using backrefs, and use a second command to remove the `,0` at the end:

```
sed -r 's/^(.{4})(.{2})(.{2}) (.{2})(.{2})(.{2})000/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/;s/,0$//' input.csv
```

The `-r` enables extended regex syntax, so that the `()` and `{}` don't need to be escaped (it is much more readable that way).

Groups in `()` are capture groups; what they match is captured for later use as `\1`, `\2` and so forth for the first, second, and subsequent groups. So in the replacement, `\1` refers to the first four characters of the line, `\2` to the two following them and so forth (these are called "back references").

The `000` are part of the pattern but not of the replacement, so they are removed by this, and the second command `s/,0$//` just removes the `,0` at the end of the line.

But if you want to stick to your approach: Since the `000` invariably appear before the first comma, you could just add

```
s/000,//
```

somewhere (or `s/...,//`, if you prefer), as in

```
sed '
  s/.\{4\}/&-/;
  s/.\{7\}/&-/;
  s/.\{13\}/&:/;
  s/.\{16\}/&:/;
  s/.\{2\}$//;
  s/000,//' input.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Can you think of any decent resources where I can learn about this stuff properly?

Comment: I always point to [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), which is great. I still use it to look things up.

Answer (score 2):

Awk version:

```
$ cat grav.awk
BEGIN { OFS=FS="" }
{
    $4 = $4 "-"
    $6 = $6 "-"
    $11 = $11 ":"
    $13 = $13 ":"
    $16=$17=$18=""
    $NF=$(NF-1)=""
}1   

$ awk -f grav.awk grav.txt
2009-05-31 23:58:50,605.530000,606.230000
2009-05-31 23:59:22,605.500000,606.200000
2009-05-31 23:59:30,605.530000,606.230000
2009-05-31 23:59:39,605.550000,606.250000
2009-05-31 23:59:45,605.500000,606.200000
2009-05-31 23:59:46,605.530000,606.230000
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not as elegant, but verbose and no awk and sed needed ;-)

Works only if the split indices are fixed.

```
while read str; do echo "${str:0:4}-${str:4:2}-${str:6:2} ${str:9:2}:${str:11:2}:${str:13:2},${str:19:21}"; done < input.csv > output.csv
```

`${str:4:2}` means: substring from index 4 with length 2

Comment: There is no benefit to using a shell loop instead of sed or awk, quite the opposite.

Comment: I see the benefit in simplicity and ease of use. Depending on the weight of the files to process, it may be a viable alternative for some folks. I was not implying it's the single one solution, just adding an option, that’s what it is about, isn't it? :-)

Comment: The awk and sed solutions are simpler and easier to use. They are also more robust (your solution will fail if the input files contain various contents such as backslashes as it'll convert `\t` to a literal tab, for example) and portable (they will work in any shell and OS) and more efficient. Showing alternatives is fine but it's not useful to propose an alternative that you should never use especially without stating the caveats (slow, non-portable, fails for some input file contents, etc....)

Comment: Ok, I see your point. thanks. Was trying to provide a working solution to a concrete problem. Nevermind, atb.

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine sed and awk to accomplish this via:

```
sed 's/.\{4\}/&-/;s/.\{7\}/&-/;s/.\{13\}/&:/;s/.\{16\}/&:/;s/,0$//' input.txt | awk '{print substr($0,1,18) substr($0,22)}' >output.txt
```

I've modified the sed command to also remove the ",0" at the end (end of line is "$" in sed). And I've added the awk command to print out two concatenated substrings around the offending "000" that you don't want (thus removing the "000").

See also, the related question: 
[I need to delete string from position X to position Y on each line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293481/i-need-to-delete-string-from-position-x-to-position-y-on-each-line-in-a-text-fil)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for fixed width fields:

```
$ awk -vFIELDWIDTHS="4 2 2 1 2 2 2 3 22 2" '{print $1"-"$2"-"$3" "$5":"$6":"$7 $9}' file
2009-05-31 23:58:50,605.530000,606.230000
2009-05-31 23:59:22,605.500000,606.200000
2009-05-31 23:59:30,605.530000,606.230000
2009-05-31 23:59:39,605.550000,606.250000
2009-05-31 23:59:45,605.500000,606.200000
2009-05-31 23:59:46,605.530000,606.230000
```